# What CSS properties can be applied to which HTML elements

Tags: html, css, specifications

I'm looking for a source/spec that can tell me what CSS properties can applied to which HTML elements.  For instance, the css property; "overflow".  I know I can apply this to div, p, textarea but what other elements can I apply this too?  Is there a spec somewhere I can reference?

Answer (score 6):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/.

For example, regarding your question about the `overflow` property, see:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow-clipping, stating:

```
'overflow'
    Value:          visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit
    Initial:        visible
    Applies to:     block-level and replaced elements
    Inherited:      no
    Percentages:    N/A
    Media:          visual
```

Comment: While technically correct, I think the OP is looking for more of a simple lookup table for quicker reference.

Comment: I must admit I'd love to see that too :) He specifically asked for a spec he could reference, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the [CSS processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#processing-model), every element has every property that is applicable to the target media type. For example, even the empty `<br>` element has the `color` property. But whether a property has an effect on the rendering of the element itself depends on the specific property and the context, in a manner that is described in applicable CSS specifications and drafts. It is usually described under an “Applies to” heading. There is no combined compilation of this, and the set of properties recognized by browsers varies considerably.

Even though a property “applies to” an element by the specifications, it need not have an actual effect. For example, `border-color` is irrelevant for the rendering of an element if its `border-style` is `none` or its `border-width` is `0`. (The value may still matter if it is inherited by child elements.)

Answer (score 2):

Any CSS property can be applied to any HTML element; they don't restrict each other.

However, as Aron Rotteveel mentioned, the element will have to be either a replaced element (like `img`), or *specified* to be block-level. That mean that the following is perfectly fine CSS:

```
strong { display: block; height: 5em; width: 5em; overflow: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the [official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/).  The answer to your particular question is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow).